# Authentication via Active Directory is creating C:\Users folders

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Active Directory to authenticate users. 
Users can log in to our site to view pages that are hidden from anonymous users, and also change their AD passwords and email addresses.

I was informed by the web server team that our site is creating folders for the users on the server.

Under C:\Users\username\ , it's creating Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc folders for everyone who signs in. We don't need these folders, and weren't aware they were being created.

All the searches I have done for this seem to turn up results for people wanting to do impersonation, and allow users to save or access these folders somehow, which is the opposite of what I want. I don't see anything in our codebase that is using impersonation (and I'm not even sure whether that would automatically create these folders or not).

This is the code for the Login Post action. Would any of this have the effect of creating a users directory on the server, or is it something else entirely? If we can't stop the folders from being created, is there a good way to delete them?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Login POST
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "UserName,Password,IsValidUser")]LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        string sUserDomain = model.UserName.Substring(0, model.UserName.IndexOf("\\"));
        string sUserName = model.UserName.Substring(model.UserName.IndexOf("\\") + 1);

        string [] parts = model.UserName.Split('\\');
        sUserDomain = parts[0];
        sUserName = parts[1];

        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View(model);
        }
        bool bValue = Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
        MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (LogonUser(sUserName, sUserDomain, model.Password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out token) != 0)
        {
            if (IsValidUser(model))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

                if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
                }

                return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            //System Error Codes
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
            //1907 = The user's password must be changed before logging on the first time.
            //1909 = The account has been locked.
            //1330 = Password has expired.
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (((error == 1907) || (error == 1330)) && (sUserDomain.ToUpper() == "EXTLCL"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordBeforeLogin", "Account");
            }
            else if (error == 1909)
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This account has been locked.");
            }
            else
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return this.View(model);
    }
```

I'm not even sure it's happening during the login. It may also be happening when users are updating their passwords. I can provide that code, also, if someone thinks it's more likely to be happening there.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found?

Comment: @BinaryPatrick No, we haven't found a solution. We've just been periodically deleting the folders.